# when will the boehm-gc 7.6 be released

Tags: boehm-gc

Boehm-gc 7.6 is on the prerelease status, When will boehm-gc 7.6 be released?
   Can we use it in product now?
   I can't found the release plan or any roadmap.
Thanks!

Comment: this should answer your question: http://www.hboehm.info/gc/

Comment: When they are ready to release it. Hard to understand why you're asking here.

Comment: It looks like [gc-7.6.0.tar.gz](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gc_source/gc-7.6.0.tar.gz) is now available in the download area.

Answer (score 2):

gc 7.6.2 will be released by Oct. At this moment, for production, I'd recommend to use gc 7.4.x or, better, checkout release-7_6 branch at https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc

Comment: However, this is not the right place for such questions and answers.